# How to share logics between view controllers for iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, subclass

Suppose, I have an `UITableViewController` for iPhone and an `UIViewController` for iPad.

These two controllers share lots of same logics. Because only `UITableViewController` supports static table view, I cannot subsidize it with an `UIViewController` (conforms `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`).

Thus, there is no way to let these view controllers subclass a common ancestor.

How to solve this problem without lots of duplicated code?

Comment: Why not just have use a UIViewController with a UITableView where needed?

Comment: I believe Xcode 5.1 requires a static table view must have a UITableViewController.

Comment: In general, you reuse your models and views, not much with the controllers. In most cases the flow of the app changes entirely with respect to iPad comparing to iPhone. You might have a navigation hierarchy in iPhone while split view hierarchy on iPad. Its better to consider iPad application different from iPhone application, albeit the models and views.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda That's true, but there are still considerable amount of code (such as validate user input, login, etc.) that does the absolute same thing. No mater it's in table view or a split view. How do we solve this problem.

Comment: The way I approach for these functionality (note these are not part of controller), is to declare a class called `Utilities` and import in all my classes using `.pch` file. These functions are then used to validate a text input, or confirm a login and stuff. I can't generalise for all the situations but if you can specify what code do you think is being reused, maybe I can suggest you an alternative  approach to the architecture.

Comment: You don't need to use a UITableViewController in order to use a UITableView.

Comment: this is asked and answered

Comment: If the common part are the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` why not move them to separate class and set it in `viewDidLoad` in both controllers?